# How to use publishNonDefault but deploy only one artifact to maven

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have a library that I am deploying to maven. The library is included in a bigger test project with multiple apps. If I set publishNonDefault to true, then in my tests apps I can use:

```
   releaseCompile project(path: ':library', configuration: 'release')
   debugCompile project(path: ':library', configuration: 'debug')
```

however, in this case mavenDeployer is automatically uploading both release and debug artifacts to maven. If I set publishNonDefault to false, then my gradle system fails, because debug flavors can not be found.

Is there any way I can use both? Use debug/release configurations locally and deploy only release as the main artifact to maven?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I ran into the same problem

Answer (score -2):

Please try this, it should work:

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Library-Publication